# How to throw an error message if username is already registered

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
   <html>
   <head>
       <style>
       .error {
        color:red;
       }
      </style>
  </head>
  <body>  

<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
include_once 'connect.php';
$nameErr = $emailErr = $usernameErr = $passwordErr = $DateOfBirthErr = $departmentErr = $ageErr = "";
$name    = $email = $username = $password = $DateOfBirth = $department = $age = "";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
        $nameErr = "Name is required";
    } else {
        $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
        // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $name)) {
            $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
        }
    }

    if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
        $emailErr = "Email is required";
    } else {
        $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
        // check if e-mail address is well-formed
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
        }
    }

    if (empty($_POST["username"])) {
        $usernameErr = "username is required";
    } else {
        $username = test_input($_POST["username"]);
        // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $username)) {
            $usernameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
        }
    }

    if (empty($_POST["password"])) {
        $passwordErr = "password is required";
    } else {
        $password        = test_input($_POST["password"]);
        $hashed_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        // check weather password is alphanumeric
        if (!preg_match('/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z])[0-9A-Za-z!@#$%]{6,}$/', $password)) {
            $passwordErr = "Password must be alphanumeric and atleast 6 characters 
    long!";
        }
    }

    if (empty($_POST["Date_of_birth"])) {
        $DateOfBirthErr = "Date Of Birth is required";
    } else {
        $DateOfBirth = test_input($_POST["Date_of_birth"]);
    }

    if (empty($_POST["department"])) {
        $departmentErr = "Department is required";
    } else {
        $department = test_input($_POST["department"]);
    }

    if (empty($_POST["age"])) {
        $ageErr = "AGE is required";
    } else {
        $age = test_input($_POST["age"]);
    }

    if ($nameErr == "" && $emailErr == "" && $usernameErr == "" && $passwordErr == "") {
        $check = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$_POST[username]'";
        $rs    = mysqli_query($mysqli, $check);
        $da    = mysqli_fetch_array($rs, MYSQLI_NUM);
        if ($da[0] > 1) {
            echo "Username Already in Exists<br/>";
        }

        else {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO users(`id`,`username`, `password`, `email` , `name` , 
   `Date_of_birth` , `department` ,`age`)
         VALUES ('','" . $username . "', '" . $hashed_password . "', '" . $email . "' , 
    '" . $name . "' , '" . $DateOfBirth . "' , '" . $department . "' , '" . $age . "')";

            if (mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql)) {
                echo "Registered successfully";
            } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($mysqli);
            }
            mysqli_close($mysqli);
        }
    }

}

function test_input($data)
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
?>

       <div style="padding-left: 250px">
    <h2>Registration Form</h2>
     <p><span class="error">All fields are required </span></p>
    <form method="post" action="">  
     Name: 
   <input type="text" name="name" style="margin-left: 52px">
    <span class="error"> <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
     <br><br>
    E-mail:
    <input type="text" name="email" style="margin-left: 48px">
     <span class="error"><?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
  Username:
   <input type="text" name="username" style="margin-left:26px">
    <span class="error"> <?php echo $usernameErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
   Password:
 <input type="password" name="password" style="margin-left:30px">
   <span class="error"> <?php echo $passwordErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
   Date Of Birth :
  <input type="date" name="Date_of_birth">
 <span class="error"> <?php echo $DateOfBirthErr;?></span>
      <br><br>
       Age :
     <input type="number" name="age" style="margin-left:62px">
 <span class="error"> <?php echo $ageErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
  Department :
   <select name="department" style="margin-left:14px">
     <option value="EE">Electrical & Electronics</option>
 <option value="EC">Electronics & Communication</option>
 <option value="ME">Mechanical</option>
     <option value="CS">Computer Science</option>
 <option value="CV">Civil</option>
    <option value="IS">Information Science</option>
  </select>
   <span class="error"> <?php echo $departmentErr;?></span>
    <br><br>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register">  
 </form>
 </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

connect.php

```
<?php

$databaseHost     = 'localhost';
$databaseName     = 'amith';
$databaseUsername = 'root';
$databasePassword = '';

$mysqli = mysqli_connect($databaseHost, $databaseUsername, $databasePassword, $databaseName);

?>
```

i'm creating a simple php registration form, i only have one issue which is not getting fixed i.e., when any one while registering enters the same username then an error message  should throw saying that username already taken i have tried with the above code but its not working. please can any one help me to fix my issue.

Answer (score 0):

before

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users(`id`,`username`, `password`, `email` , 
  `name` , `Date_of_birth` , `department` ,`age`)
         VALUES ('','".$username."', '".$hashed_password."', '".$email."' , 
   '".$name."' , '".$DateOfBirth."' , '".$department."' , '".$age."')";
```

You can write SQL to check if username is exist or not :

SQL : `'SELECT username from users where username = $username';`

If this query returns result with count more than 0 then show an error message as 'This Username already exists';
If it gives you 0 results then proceed with INSERT functionality.

Comment: can u please edit in my code n tel me because what u told i tried but m not getting the output

Comment: Try printing value of `$da[0]`, if it is 1, then change the condition as `if($da[0]>0)`

Answer (score 0):

Before you insert the new user you can query for the username with a select like:

```
SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$username'
```

If this query returns more than 0 rows the username exists already.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try like this

variable should be like this  $_POST['username']

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO users(`id`,`username`, `password`, `email` , `name` ,`Date_of_birth` , `department` ,`age`) VALUES ('', ".$username.", ".$hashed_password.", ".$email." , ".$name." , ".$DateOfBirth." , ".$department." , ".$age.")";
```

Answer (score 0):

An effective way to tackle this unique username problem is to validate the username at the time of entry from UI.

**Step 1**:in html input box there should be jquery or js function call to a php page with entered username as argument.

**Step 2** the backend php scrpt will simple check the username in database and if exists the will return a JSON o/p that userbane alreasy exist else it will return true.

**Step 3**:show the message to on UI with simple Js and block further processing of form.

Also you must check the uniqueness of username after form submit and before insert into your data base table to avoid concurrent submit by two different user with same username.
**Also if possible make sure username is primary key in your database table to avoid concurrent submit with same username problem**,This will add another solid layer of protection at the bottom.

```
<input type="text" name="uname" id="uname" onblur="unameOnBlur(this.value);">
```

You can do it onkeyup or any suitable event also.
 inside unameOnBlur make an ajax call like

```
$.ajax({
                    url: 'json_uname.php?uname=' + uname,
                    dataType: 'json'
                }).done(function (j){
if(username unique)
//your action code
 })
```

the above one is sample ajax call example
Json_uname.php page is simple to write to check against db.